# Conditional transaction rollback

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, sql-server-2012, rollback

I am wondering, if there is a possibility to apply conditional transaction rollback based on state of particular batch. For example, I have a following code:

```
BEGIN TRAN 
--EXEC No 1
    EXEC [dbo].[MyProc] 1;
    GO
--EXEC No 2
    EXEC [dbo].[MyProc] 22;
    GO
--EXEC No 3
    EXEC [dbo].[MyProc] 333;
    GO
--EXEC No 4
    EXEC [dbo].[MyProc] 5;
    GO
COMMIT
```

And I want to rollback entire transaction if the `EXEC No 3` fails. If any other execution fails I want SQL Server to continue executing my query. Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "fail"?

Comment: Let's say, Update No 3 concerns table, that doesn't exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Begin tran
Begin try
.....
commit
End try
begin catch
rollback
End catch
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms175976.aspx

They prefer to do the begin tran and commit outside

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. Use TRY/CATCH blocks around each procedure call, determine how to handle errors for each procedure in each respective CATCH block.

In your case, only perform a ROLLBACK in the CATCH block for the third procedure call.